# Footage inside footage

Tags: compositing-nodes

With this node system I was able to put the footage inside the footage in a specific area identified by the Plane Track that I have created.
[image]
I was wondering how should I modify the nodes in order to reiterate the process, I mean the footage inside the footage inside the footage etc.

Answer (score 1):

We need to repeat the three nodes *Image*, *Plane Track Deform* and *Alpha Over* and feed these three nodes into the following *Plane Track Deform* node.

[image]

Comment: You're freaking meow't

Comment: It would be better to describe textually what the three nodes circled in yellow are so that the indexing system makes them available for anyone searching for it. It also makes it easier to know what they are since the image is tiny and the nodes barely legible. Could you edit your post and improve these points? Thanks